# Using same callback for two ajax() request yields "parsererror"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I've been battling with Javascript for a little while now and I have a weird error which is probably something simple. I have an ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.hahaha.com/api/v3/acts',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'handlejson',
    async: false,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: handleActs,
    error: handleError
});
```

Which works fine and calls the callback with no problems. Now, if I add this request directly underneath:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.hahaha.com/api/v3/performances',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'handlejson',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: handlePerformances,
    error: handleError
});
```

I get a "parsererror" on the first request and the second one succeeds. Anyone have any ideas as to why it's doing this? Can a jsonpCallback only have one request called on it?

Comment: are you sure ist request is returning json??

Comment: I'm using the Chrome developer tools and both requests return valid JSON, the parsererror only happens when I add the second request

Comment: Does reversing the order of the calls make any difference? I.e. does it still fail on the second request, or is it the call to `/performances` that causes the error?

Comment: Weird...if I reverse them, the handlejson function isn't called on /acts but the data is still sent to handleActs. When /performances finishes, the handlejson function is called and the data is sent to handlePerformances. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it works to have two AJAX calls referring to the same `jsonpCallback` - I think jQuery puts a callback function in the global namespace, then *removes* it when it's called - so it won't be around for the second set of loaded data. I wouldn't have thought this would matter with `async` set to `false`, but it looks like it does.

At first I couldn't figure out why you were setting `jsonpCallback` at all, but testing seems to indicate that the API you're using strips anything other than `[a-z]` from the callback name :(. So you might try this with `jsonpCallback` set to `'handlejsona'` in the first call and `'handlejsonb'` in the second call.

This approach seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/H7zYt/

Comment: A colleague of mine confirms this - you can't use the same callback for two different ajax requests. For example, Angular JS creates a unique callback for each request.